# How to properly make REST PUT operations Idempotent when using versioning

Tags: rest, http

I know that REST PUT operations are supposed to be idempotent.  And I know that they are designed to support versioning (so if I try to update an object where I had old version 4, but the new version is 5, I should get a 409 Conflict response.  But what is the proper way to handle idempotency and versioning?

Let's say my objects have a version and a single data-field (e.g. 'name').  If my current object is located at /objects/1, and had version 1 with name 'alice', and I wanted to update it to version 2 with nam 'bob', I would presumably send a PUT with version 2 and name 'bob'.  But because it is idempotent, I should be able to send it repeatedly and have the effect be the same as a single call.  Subsequent calls would normally fail the versioning check, except that their other data will match what is on the server, and can be detected as (or at least assumed to be) duplicate requests.

Should the responses to all repeated calls be the same (e.g. 200 OK or 204 No Content)?  Or should the response code indicate whether the call actually made a change (and incremented the version), or whether it was detected as a repeat call (what would otherwise be flagged as a 409 Conflict except for the fact that the data in the PUT was the same as what was already there)?  And if it should indicate the difference, what is the appropriate way to distinguish them in the response?

And, I suppose I should also ask whether REST versioning is typically done in the object (e.g. with a version field of the REST object), or whether it is done in the REST protocol (e.g. as an HTTP field, keeping the object "clean")?

Comment: Properties like `idempotent` and `safe` are in regards to the transport of the request and not necessarily on the retrieval of the resource state. The versioning of the resource is usually done via ETag or If-Modified-Since (and similar) headers. ETag generates a hash value of the resource's state and wont change if you apply the update multiple times. The last modification timestamp is a bit different. As you should replace the content with the one received you actually should also update the modification timestamp, though this may be a thing to discuss actually. I'd recommend using ETags

Comment: I'm not a fan of If-Modified-Since for versioning, since the granularity is only 1 second, so there could be false-positives if there is high-frequency updating.  As for using ETags for versioning, it certainly works for "is it the same or not", but it seems to lose some of the monotonicly-updated-series-of-versions that a simple auto-incremented integer provides.  If I try to update an object I thought was at version 4, it's nice to know that the actual version is 6 (or 10) instead of just knowing that it's something different.

Comment: HTTP is not a versioning protocol actually. If you want such a feature you either need to switch to such a dedicated protocol or use a certain link structure that you can emulate such a feature.

Comment: That's why I was planning to do it within my object - have a version field.  Then, on a PUT, the server would check to see whether the PUT version is the server version +1 (or, to detect duplicate calls, whether it is the same as the server version, and that all the contents are the same).  Is this not how applications that do versioning over REST usually do it?

Comment: HTTP doesn't instruct you to keep track of all the changes done to a resource over time. This is some internal detail. It usually only deals with the most recent state where ETag works sufficiently enough. If you need to return i.e. a previous state (i.e. similar like git does), you probably could introduce branch-resources that contain a linked list of modifications that changed the resource and so provide a way to retrieve previous versions of the resource. Not sure though if that is what you really want to achive

Comment: I recognize that HTTP doesn't (necessarily) provide versioning, but my understanding was that it supports application-level versioning vis-a-vis the 409 Conflict response - allows the application to say "your PUT was based on an old version, here's some human and/or computer readable information on how it was different".  Then the application can do what it wants to (e.g. maybe just re-GET it and try again, maybe display the error to the user, whatever).  Is my desire to implement application-level versioning, and use the HTTP 409 response to indicate a conflict not the right way to go?

Comment: Should you ever update the non-current version? I would argue that you should not. I think it is a minor crime to make an idempotency exception by incrementing the version number on each PUT request, as long as all resource data remains the same.

Comment: I wouldn't increment - I'd just allow it to succeed when the version check would otherwise have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the responses to all repeated calls be the same (e.g. 200 OK or 204 No Content)?

Yes - the relevant part of the HTTP specification is in [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232). Review the description of [If-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1):

> An origin server MUST NOT perform the requested method if a received If-Match condition evaluates to false; instead, the origin server MUST respond with either a) the 412 (Precondition Failed) status code or b) one of the 2xx (Successful) status codes if the origin server has verified that a state change is being requested and the final state is already reflected in the current state of the target resource (i.e., the change requested by the user agent has already succeeded, but the user agent might not be aware of it, perhaps because the prior response was lost or a compatible change was made by some other user agent).  In the latter case, the origin server MUST NOT send a validator header field in the response unless it can verify that the request is a duplicate of an immediately prior change made by the same user agent.

My reading of this is that the server isn't *required* to verify that the change has already succeeded; but if it performs such a check, and wants to communicate the result to the client, that's the way to do it.

I don't see any reason why the same logic wouldn't apply where you might use the [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code instead.

> I suppose I should also ask whether REST versioning is typically done in the object (e.g. with a version field of the REST object), or whether it is done in the REST protocol (e.g. as an HTTP field, keeping the object "clean")?

Not all media types make it convenient to embed versioning metadata in the representation of a resource (we use the same PUT for images that we use for json documents), so I would guess that it is more typical to see the versioning information in the meta data (which is to say, in the headers as described by [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)).

> And if it should indicate the difference, what is the appropriate way to distinguish them in the response?

Unspecified; you can do what makes sense there.  In the case of "success", you should be sending "a representation of the status of the action" along with a 2xx class status code (see [RFC 7231 6.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)).  With a `409 Conflict` / `412 Precondition Failed` - since those status codes are members of the 4xx class, you should send "a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition" (see [RFC 7231 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)).

It might be helpful to review the example in [RFC 7807 Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807#section-4.1).

Comment: As I mentioned in one of my comments above, I'm not happy with the HTTP level validators supported in the If-Match - timestamps are to coarse, and ETags are too opaque.  I'd like to use monotonically increasing integer versions.  Am I "breaking the rules" by trying to use HTTP response codes/headers to express information that comes from the application level (e.g. my object-embedded version check)?

Comment: @Doug On reading what RFC 7232 states on [ETag](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3) it actually doesn't prescribe how the ETag is generated. In fact it even states that the ETag might be some internal versioning number.

Comment: Ah - I'd only ever seen checksums for etags.  If that's the case, then it seems like the right answer.